# In K2 designer, how to split a table cell?

Tags: k2, k2-blackpearl

I'm using K2 designer to build an ItemView, but, someone in my project merged some cells in the layout table.

Is there a way to split this cell again?

Here is what i'm saying
[Table layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YaVlg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help you,

The only option to remove the merge is to remove the column by selection the merge cell and then add a column to the left.

Keep in mind it remove the column so all controls need to be out of that column otherwise you going to have to recreate them.

[image: Remove Merge Cell]